# Is there a table somewhere underlining the difference between these git commands?

Tags: git, git-detached-head, git-describe

It seems there is some overlap in those git sub-commands:

- describe
- rev-parse
- name-rev
- symbolic-ref
- show-ref

Is there a nice table somewhere which underlines what some of them can not do? It should cover:

- failure indication
- reading/writing
- flexibility with output details
- listing all or one
- search around/exact

Answer (score 0):

If a subcommand is not listed, it can’t do that operation.

- branch → sha1 (short)

  - `git rev-parse (--short) [[refs/]heads/]branch`
  - `git show-ref --hash (--abbrev) [[refs/]heads/]branch`
- tag → sha1 (of the first object in a possible chain)

  - same as branch → sha1, but ...
  - use `[[refs/]tags/]tag`
- tag → sha1 (of final commit object in a tag chain)

  - `git rev-parse [[refs/]tags/]tag^{}`

    - this is a general mechanism which works in most commands
  - `git show-ref` can be used with `--dereference`, but you still have to grep for the sha1

TBC

- sha1 → branch

  - exact
  - search
- sha1 → tag

  - exact
  - search
- HEAD→branch
- HEAD→sha1
- HEAD-alikes→branch
- HEAD-alikes→sha1
- sha1→HEAD-alike